# Components won't auto-resizing when using JFXDecorator, how to fix that?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use JFXDecorator to fancy a look of a Window of my application. But using it brokes an auto-resize of components. This is what my code looks like

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ApplicationView.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(stage, root);
    decorator.setCustomMaximize(true);

    stage.setTitle("Weather API");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(decorator));

    String cssURI = getClass().getResource("stylesheet/style.css").toExternalForm();
    decorator.getStylesheets().add(cssURI);

    stage.show();
}
```

And this is the effect, look at the split-pane.

[image: window is broken]

Without **JFXDecorator** works normally with code like below.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ApplicationView.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    stage.setTitle("Weather API");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    String cssURI = getClass().getResource("stylesheet/style.css").toExternalForm();

    stage.show();
}
```

[image: works]

I tried to set AncorPane properties of main pane similar to childs so maybe it will resising but it failed. My FXML looks like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" stylesheets="@stylesheet/style.css" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.161">
   <children>
     <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

How can I fix it? Thank You.

Comment: Show minimal-complete `FXML` with fault.

Comment: I attached full FXML by now

Comment: This `FXML` seems to the be the one that is working the way you want it to work.

Comment: Okay, yea looks like a problem.

Comment: It does not make sense, but when I made the `SplitPane` the root `FXML` node it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `AnchorPane` and make the `SplitPane` the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </items>
</SplitPane>
```